# How to avoid PHP APCu cache clearing while restarting apache on Ubuntu

Tags: php, apcu

I have setup the PHP APCu caching on my Ubuntu machine. But the problem is that cached data is clearing on every time restarting apache. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. PHP runs as an apache process, when it's stopped, it will clear the APC as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP run as apache process you cannot do it so easly. But you can use php-fpm with apache and then they will be two independent processes. You will only need to install php-fpm, run in and in apache vhost configuration put:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/your/documentroot/$1
DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php
```

More information on configuring apache with php-fpm can be found [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM)